# No puedo ver la caja de los checkbox

Tags: html, css

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap para los estilos y me he fijado que al poner un checkbox este no se muestra en pantalla.

**Solo me pasa con google chrome.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo html y css de esa parte.

```css
.bootstrap-switch input[type='radio'],
.bootstrap-switch input[type='checkbox'] {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-group-toggle > .btn input[type="radio"],
.btn-group-toggle > .btn input[type="checkbox"],
.btn-group-toggle > .btn-group > .btn input[type="radio"],
.btn-group-toggle > .btn-group > .btn input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Inicio </h1>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Por que podría pasar esto? Lo curioso es que fuera de mi programa si funciona bien.

Comment: Puedes escribir el código en forma de texto y el css relevante?

Comment: Tienes que mostrar los codigos relacionados, copiandolos y pegandolos en formato.

Comment: No hay problema con el código que muestras. Creo que tienes algo en el css que "sobrescribir" el css de checkbox.

Comment: No veo que pase nada en firefox, tal vez sea un problema específico de chrome

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a darle alto, ancho y alineación:

```css
.form-check {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Inicio </h1>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```